# Invalid Column Name when using T-SQL column alias

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting started with `T-SQL`, but appear to be misunderstanding the column alias concepts. I've tried searching for a answer to this without success, though I'm sure it must be something very simple to a more experienced developer. I'm using `SQL Server 2008`.

```
select FirstName as nick
from [Dev].[dbo].[Name]
where nick like '%et%'
order by nick desc
```

Error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Invalid column name 'nick'.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select FirstName as nick
from [Dev].[dbo].[Name]
where FirstName like '%et%' -- There is no such column "nick" in your table
order by 1 desc
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do it.

```
SELECT FirstName as nick
FROM Dev.dbo.Name
WHERE FirstName like '%et%'
ORDER BY FirstName DESC
```

Comment: Huh? I answered first, but you got the tick? Ripped off! :)

Comment: @Bohemian sorry about that.  +1 to make up for it.